Difference in meaning using у with or without есть
What is the difference in meaning of these two statements?

У Анны есть деньги.
Деньги у Анны.

They seem nearly identical in meaning to me, but I am thinking the difference may be that the first more emphasizes the fact of possession of a specific item. Is that right? Is it correct to say something like “The money belongs to Anna” for the first vs “Anna has some money” for the second?

Both versions are translated equally in English: Anna has the money. First version is a simple fact. Second version is usually used in conversation: У кого деньги? Деньги у Анны. (Who has the money? Anna does.)

It's actually the other way around.
У Анны есть деньги means "Anna has money". Depending on context, it might mean that she's wealthy, or that she has enough money for something, or that she has some money at all.
Деньги у Анны means "Anna has the money", or, better yet, "it's Anna who has the money". This phrase, as its English counterparts, can't be used in isolation. It should be a development of a previous conversation about some particular money, and the news is that it's Anna who has it.

During one Russian course I took, the instructor often asked the students if we had questions by saying "Какие у вас вопросы?"  I once asked her why she did not say "Какие у вас есть вопросы?" and she explained that she expected we should have questions and that meant the есть was not appropriate.
